# How to continue a message box?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I want to write a code that continues the message box after receiving an answer.
for example: If they answer yes they get another message box, and same applies for no.

I'm not sure how to word it correctly i hope it makes sense.

I've tried with this:

```py
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title = "Reginának" , message = "Mizu?")
answer = (tkinter.messagebox.askyesno = "yes")
if answer != "yes"
tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title = "Reginának" , message = "Persze")
```

Although i do know that it's not right i was just trying to do something with my limited knowledge :))

Comment: you can make as many message boxes as you like. Presumably you want a different question each time, so please provide sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

ws = Tk()
ws.title('Python Guides')
ws.geometry('300x200')
ws.config(bg='#5FB691')

res = messagebox.askquestion('Reginának', '"Mizu?')
if res == 'yes':
    messagebox.showinfo('Reginának', 'Persze')
elif res == 'no':
    messagebox.showinfo('Reginának', 'You must be a Pele\'s fan.')
else:
    messagebox.showwarning('error', 'Something went wrong!')
 
ws.mainloop()
```